# Как задать размеры Axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Для построения графиков мне необходимы три поля Axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9.5), nrows = 3, sharex=True)

plt.show()
```

Получаю три одинаковых поля. Но мне необходимо, чтобы чтобы эти Axes имели разные размеры (по высоте и ширине) на одной figure, и при этом сохранялось авто масштабирование на всех полях. Как задать конкретные размеры для ax1, ax2, ax3? Спасибо!
[image: исходное состояние]

[image: Конечное состояние]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример разного построения размеров `axes`:

Есть возможность установить размер фигуры и размер подзаголовков внутри фигуры индивидуально с помощью `gridspec_kw`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(9,16), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 2]})

axs[0].plot()
axs[1].plot()
```

Comment: @Tehnobot в вашем коде это расположение полей на фигуре, а установление размеров каждой axes. Авто масштабирование во всех ax работать не будет.  В моём случае больше необходимо, чтоб поля имели разную высоту.

Comment: @Tehnobot Ваш пример хорош и наверное подходит мне. Только не получается адаптировать под три поля, чтоб два широких одинаковых, а третье узкое поле (как на рисунке). Спасибо!

Comment: @Tehnobot всё, разобрался fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(9,16),sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 2, 1]})...спасибо за хороший совет!

Comment: @Aleksandr A Pashayev не за что, обращайтесь)

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что это то, что вам нужно, но можно воспользоваться методом `mosaic`, где вы наглядно для себя можете расположить холсты на фигуре так, как вам нужно:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mosaic = '''
AAAB
CDDB
CEEB
'''
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)
```

Теперь к каждой `axes` можно обращаться по имени, заданному в переменной `mosaic`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соответственно, при

```
mosaic = '''
AAAB
CDDB
CEEB
'''
```

получите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]